# How to grab URL of a video hidden in code with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a website that is playing videos.

But the videos are not visible from the web, but I can see them using Firefox develop tool, at the network tab.

Is there a way to grab the videos or the URL in order to download them??

The web is: https://acloud.guru/

We don't need an account to watch the promo video,

https://acloud.guru/learn/lpic-1

And how to scrap the video with python.

I can only see it with the developer tools, network tab in Firefox

Comment: What website are you referring to?

Comment: https://acloud.guru/learn/lpic-1. The promo video is an example of all other videos

Answer (score 0):

Looked through the network tab on their website.  I found that it loads a JSON list of videos at `query?x...`.  I'd start there.  Simply open up network tab, refresh the page, then click on the 'response tab.'  From there CTRL+A, CTRL+C.  And now you've scraped all the video urls.  It should start with `{"hits":[{"allowDownload":true...`.

Comment: i mean, how to find that list of videos using python??